# How can I set minDate in DatePickerDialog to be after 2 days

Tags: android, date, time, picker

I created a DatePickerDialog in my Activity, and I am trying to set the minDate to after 2 days.

For example, today is **25/5/2015**, and I want the minDate to be: **27/5/2015**

This is the code:

```
final DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(TestActivity.this,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                ,calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                ,calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        DatePicker dp = dpd.getDatePicker();

        dp.setMinDate(//I want to set it to after 2 days);
```

I tried this but I got an error:

```
dp.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000);
```

So how can it be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why +2000? Thats 2 seconds.

Comment: Shouldn't it be dp.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2*24*60*60*1000)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 2);
dp.setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // where  DatePicker dp
```

Answer (score 0):

Mithuns answer is correct, but the following should also work:

```
dp.setMinDate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 2*24*60*60*1000));
```

Because `Date` is just a wrapper for `Long`.